# Bootstrap: why is my Modal transparent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use a Modal from the Bootstrap library.

When I click the button, the Modal is displayed, but it is **transparent.**

I can't figure out why this is.

**JSFiddle link:**
http://jsfiddle.net/0cqkdjey/

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="loginWindow" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="model-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 id="loginLabel" class="modal-title">Log in</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input id="email" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <p>blablabla</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    // set focus when modal is opened
    $('#loginWindow').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#email').focus();
    });

    // everytime the button is pushed, open the modal, and trigger the shown.bs.modal event
    $('#loginButton').click(function () {
        $('#loginWindow').modal({
            show: true
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: check that your CSS does not have the property `backdrop` set to `false` - Also, are you Boostrap 2.x syntax with Boostrap 3.x libraries?

Comment: I have Bootstrap 3. Which part is Bootstrap 2 syntax?

Comment: Ah, I see the fiddle now, let me check it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found it:

```
<div class="model-content">
```

Should be:

```
<div class="modal-content"> // Notice the a
```

That should fix it.

Cheers!